# FTP User/Group permission on VSFTPD and UBUNTU

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, chmod, vsftpd, chown

I developed a vsftp server with three user groups: `g1`, `g2`, `g3`. Each group has a folder with its name. For example.

```
/home/server/g1
/home/server/g2
/home/server/g3
```

Each group also has users

```
sudo useradd -g g1 u1
sudo useradd -g g1 u2
sudo useradd -g g2 u3
sudo useradd -g g2 u4
sudo useradd -g g3 u5
```

Users in group 1 can only access the folders in group 1 Users in group 2 can only access the folders in group 2 Users in Group 3 can access the folders of all groups.

Users in Group 1 can not delete folders that do not belong to them. Example: u1 tries to delete the u2 folder located at `home/server/g1/u2`.

Which command should I use to get this type of permission?

Only users in Group 3 can delete the folders in the other groups. Example: u5 can delete the `home/server/g2/u4` folder.

To get these permissions I used the following commands.

```
sudo chown -c -R g3 home/server/g1
sudo chown -c -R g3 home/server/g2
```

But it did not work either.

Which parameters should I use in the chown command to get the required permissions? Would not the `-c` parameter be usefulfor that?